# Datetime in django with template filter will show different value

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django template filters to format a datetime instance, but it looks like its value differs from raw date in the datebase.

I used `datetime.now()` in `Python` to create the instance.

```
{{ modeltest.date }}
```

will show

```
"Jan. 3, 2019, 5:27 a.m."
```

on the page, but

```
{{ modeltest.date | date:"Y-m-d H:m:s" }}
```

displays

```
"2019-01-03 05:01:19"
```

Note the difference of the minutes displayed (`5:27` vs `05:01`)

I'm getting a little confused here.
Does anyone know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up the [date filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date). You used the month twice (lowercase `m`) instead of using minutes (lowercase `i`).

You are seeing `"2019-01-03 05:01:19"` (with the minutes as `01` instead of `27`) because it actually show the month (January is the first month, so `01`).

---

You can change this

```
date:"Y-m-d H:m:s"
```

to

```
date:"Y-m-d H:i:s"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You said that I was mixing up the filters in Django!